# How to build qt 5 project on mac

Tags: macos, qt, clang

I try to build a simple Qt 5 program on Mac. But I failed.

The code is very simple:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

I used:

```
clang++ -I ~/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/include -L/Users/crazylion/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib    test.cpp
```

Then I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QApplication::exec()", referenced from:
      _main in test-jPGORy.o
  "QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-jPGORy.o
  "QApplication::~QApplication()", referenced from:
      _main in test-jPGORy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there anything i missing?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't compile and link Qt projects by hand; use qmake and project files.

Run `qmake -project` in your source directory to generate a basic project file.

Edit the project file and add the following line: `QT += widgets`

Now run `qmake` to generate a makefile.

Now run `make` to build your program.

Secondly, you can simply `#include <QApplication>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use clang++ in favor of qmake, you need to specify libraries to link against to, along with the library directory (which you supplied).

```
clang++ -I ~/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/include -L/Users/crazylion/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/clang_64/lib  -lQtCore -lQtGui  test.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and it seems to me that there is some sort of bug in the release it gave me some errors because out of a fresh install  (using qt creator) i didn't have some obscure qt library (not the normal qt5 modules but some sort of library in development) so I tend to think that it could be qt's problem

That said I have some questions to better understand:

-are you using a IDE?

-if you are using one which is it?

-are you including all the modules in the *.pro for quake?

-have you used 4.8 version, did you experienced these problems with that?

P.S. if you do not have any particular necessity I suggest you to stick to version 4.8 for some time (as I am doing without problem) since 5.0 is just been released